# Is there a generic way to add secondary axis in ggplot without scaling?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I want to have lines for the MAPE and Accuracy on the same plot using ggplot to see how they change over different clusters. I tried different solutions like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/ggplot-with-2-y-axes-on-each-side-and-different-scales), however, they do not work. Here is my data:

```
data = structure(list(Clusters = c("1 Cluster", "2 Clusters", "3 Clusters", 
"4 Clusters", "5 Clusters", "6 Clusters", "7 Clusters", "8 Clusters"
), Accuracy = c("100", "72.4", "60.5", "42.4", "34.6", "24.7", 
"25.5", "22.4"), MAPE = c("138.604968", "130.1682745", "107.7288902", 
"156.0743566", "126.7168457", "144.2963746", "130.2850425", "134.7150458"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Here is what I am trying but I cannot scale the MAPE and Accuracy to the same scale:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Clusters, y = Accuracy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line(aes(y = MAPE))+
  scale_y_continuous(
    "MAPE (%)", 
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name = "MAPE (%)")
  )
```

Comment: Can you include the code that you tried, and the output, and explain what is meant by "they do not work".

Comment: Two issues: (1) your example data results in "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" because the y-variables are of type character, not numeric - remove the quotes around the numeric values. (2) your code only plots one y-variable; one solution is to reshape the data to long format first.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, there's no need for a second axis if the scale is the same.  But leaving that aside, there are a couple of issues with your data and code.

First, the y-variables are not numeric so let's fix that:

```
dataset <- structure(list(Clusters = c("1 Cluster", "2 Clusters", "3 Clusters", 
                                   "4 Clusters", "5 Clusters", "6 Clusters", "7 Clusters", "8 Clusters"
), Accuracy = c(100, 72.4, 60.5, 42.4, 34.6, 24.7, 
                25.5, 22.4), MAPE = c(138.604968, 130.1682745, 107.7288902, 
                                          156.0743566, 126.7168457, 144.2963746, 130.2850425, 134.7150458
                )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Second, if you want to plot multiple variables on the y-axis, it's better to reshape the data into long format with one column for names, one for values. You can use `tidyr::pivot_longer()`:

```
dataset %>%
  pivot_longer(-Clusters) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Clusters, y = value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = name)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group = name))+
  scale_y_continuous("MAPE (%)", 
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name = "Accuracy (%)"))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: In this plot, the y-axis on the two sides has the same values. Is it possible to put the accuracy first and accordingly add the MAPE by changing the scale of the other y-axis to have the MAPE on the same plot of the accuracy?

Comment: Your question says "I cannot scale the MAPE and Accuracy to the same scale" so I'm not sure what you are asking here. Do you mean that you want different ranges on each scale? So for example MAPE could be 100-160 and Accuracy would be 20-120?

Comment: Yes, I want them to be two separate normal axes. They need to be in different ranges.

Comment: Thinking about this some more, I don't think this is a good use case for a secondary axis. You need to transform the values on the primary axis somehow and in this case, because MAPE is basically Accuracy + around 60 to 80, transformation is not as effective as say a division or multiplication would be. So I think I would consider reshaping to long format data and using `facet_wrap` with a free y-scale instead.